# Issues with installing virtualmin on a running webmin installation

Tags: virtualmin

I currently have a machine serving a couple of clients sites.  In order to make maintaining the system easier I installed webmin and set up the sites using the virtual domains feature.

I now need to add more virtual servers and in hindsight see that I should have installed virtualmin on a clean installation when I set the machine up but given that there are sites configured and up and running will virtualmin still install nicely now?

Will it read the config files and allow me to administer them through virtualmin without anything breaking or should I rebuild the server from scratch?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looked into this a while back and unfortunately there was no safe upgrade path. (This makes sense to me, being familiar with both Webmin and Virtualmin and thinking about how it would convert vhosts, database users, mail config, etc., etc.)

I think I remember more recent threads in the forum, but could only find [Uninstall Webmin & Virtualmin GPL before installing Virtualmin Pro?](http://www.virtualmin.com/node/5197).

I decided to set up a new box, install VM and port the sites over manually. I was lucky -- on a VPS with only a few sites.

Definitely rebuild.